# Adding list of numbers to existing csv

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv

I am attempting to add a list of numbers to an existing csv file.  Seems like it should be easy but I can't get the correct output.  For example, let's say `test.csv` has

```
0,0

1,1

2,2

3,3

4,4
```

and `C=[0,1,2,3,4]`

I want to do this for any length list `j` that matches the number of rows in test.  I want `test.csv` to be

```
0,0,0

1,1,1

2,2,2

3,3,3

4,4,4
```

Any help is appreciated.

thank you for your response.

I attempted this in the following way:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## import data

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

## initialize list

list_A = [0,1,2,3,4]

## change list to series

series_A = pd.Series(list_A)

## save series as dataframe column

df[1] = series_A.values

and was greeted with this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2299, in **setitem**
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2366, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2524, in _sanitize_column
    value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2741, in _sanitize_index
    raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of '
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

> > > df[0] = series_A.values
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2299, in **setitem**
> > >           self._set_item(key, value)
> > >         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2366, in _set_item
> > >           value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
> > >         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2524, in _sanitize_column
> > >           value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
> > >         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2741, in _sanitize_index
> > >           raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of '
> > >       ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: Please provide us with your full reproducible code so that we can better assist you.

Comment: Read the data into a two-dimensional list, append data to this list, write the list to the file. Where exactly are you facing issues?

Comment: Not to be mean but you said you generally use `csv` package but you don't know how to write stuff using it?

Comment: Why use `csv.reader` and `savetxt` when you tag the question with `pandas`? You're likely better off (easier) with Pandas in the first place. `savetxt` is even NumPy, which I don't see mentioned at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to do with [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/).

General Process:

- Read in the CSV file as a pandas DataFrame.
- Change the list to series
- Append the series to the DataFrame
- Save the DataFrame

Written code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#import data
df = pd.read_csv('Your_Filename.csv')

#initialize list
list_A = np.arange(365)
list_B = np.arange(365)*2

#change list to series
series_A = pd.Series(list_A)
series_B = pd.Series(list_B) 

#save series as dataframe column
df['column_name_A'] = series_A.values
df['column_name_B'] = series_B.values

#save dataframe to csv
df.to_csv('output_filename.csv')
```